# Where can I get a copy of Monsters of Myth?

Tags: adnd-1e, osr

I was wondering where I could get a softcover copy of the OSRIC book, [Monsters of Myth](http://black-blade-publishing.com/Store/tabid/65/pid/40/Monsters-of-Myth-Hardback-print-.aspx). 
Any help would be great.

Comment: Hi Aang.  This question isn't really a good fit for the site, as it takes no RPG expertise to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try Black Blade Publishing, they put out a high quality version of both the OSRIC rules and the Monsters of Myth book: http://black-blade-publishing.com/Home.aspx

The softcover is no longer available. My best thought would be to get the pdf (which is free) and have it printed out by a professional printing service in PB form (let them bind it for you).

Comment: I was hoping to get the soft cover copy.

Comment: Why was this voted down? It answers the question in a useful way.

Comment: I've stopped asking questions here why anything is voted up or down, why some topics are closed and some aren't, it'll just give you a headache...just happy to put the information out there!